# Manipulating the elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Let's create some sample data

```
tab = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, -3, 3}, {j, -3, 3}, {k, -3, 3}];
ICs = Flatten[tab, 2];
Nt = Length[ICs];
```

A $3\times3$ system of equations

```
f = x^2 - 2*x + y^2 - z + 1;
g = x*y^2 - x - 3*y + y*z + 2;
h = x*z^2 - 3*z + y*z^2 + x*y;
```

and its numerical solution

```
sol0 = NSolve[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

Now let's assign an integer number to each solution

```
rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{sol0[[;; , ;; , 2]], Range[Length[sol0]]}]
```

Finally we define an iterative procedure

```
data = {};
For[j = 1, j <= Nt, j++, 
  x0 = ICs[[j, 1]]; 
  y0 = ICs[[j, 2]];
  z0 = ICs[[j, 3]];
  sol = FindRoot[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0}, {x, x0}, {y, y0}, {z, z0}];
  xf = x /. sol[[1]];
  yf = y /. sol[[2]];
  zf = z /. sol[[3]];
  AppendTo[data, {x0, y0, z0, xf, yf, zf}]
]
```

For some initial conditions the `FindRoot` works well, while for some other it fails to converge to one of the five solutions. The results are stored to `data` list.

I would like to obtain a new table, `data2` in which the first three elements `x0,y0,z0` to be the same as in `data`, while the forth element to be the corresponding integer according to the above rule. If `xf,yf,zf` do match with one of the five solutions then the new list should contain the corresponding integer on the forth column. If they do not match a 0 should be assigned. How can I achieve this?

A minor issue: I know that `FindRoot` uses the Newton-Raphson method in order to solve a system of equations. Is possible to include in `data` list the number of iterations needed by the Newton-Raphson iterative method for converging to a solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "I know that `FindRoot` uses the Newton-Raphson method in order to solve a system of equations" - well, with [a few modifications...](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodRoot.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sol0 = NSolve[{f, g, h}, {x, y, z}, Reals]

rules = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, {x, y, z} /. sol0]

data = Quiet[
  Function[{x0, y0, z0}, {x0, y0, z0, x, y, z} /. 
     FindRoot[{f, g, h}, {x, x0}, {y, y0}, {z, z0}]] @@@ ICs]

data2 = Flatten /@ 
  Replace[Partition[#, 3] & /@ 
    data, ({l1_, l2_} /; Chop@Total[(l2 - #)^2] == 0 :> {l1, #2} & @@@ rules)~
    Join~{{l1_, l2_} :> {l1, 0}}, {1}]
```

As to the "minor" issue, start from checking the document of `StepMonitor` and `EvaluationMonitor`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you create the initial `data` list in a different way? Is it because the `For` loop is a little bit slow?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Just for conciseness and… fun :D . Though `For` is slow, it's not a big deal in your case.